# Backbone.js: "Remove nonexistent models if appropriate" fails

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I don't know how to ask this but I'll try to be as specific and as comprehensible as I can.

I am working on application based on Backbone and Marionette which is fetching data from back-end api server. We have got some input field with auto-completion which works fine but just first time. Second time I'd type something the auto-complete crashes. Ehm, not exactly the auto-complete but the backbone.js itself. I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cid' of undefined backbone.js:716
_.extend.set backbone.js:716
Backbone.Collection.set backbone-relational.js:1851
_.extend.fetch.options.success backbone.js:860
Backbone.Paginator.Paginator.requestPager.Backbone.Collection.extend.sync.queryOptions.success backbone.paginator.js:840
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery.js:3073
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery.js:3185
done jquery.js:8251
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback jquery.js:8598
```

Probably between two calls to retrieving data from api server I somewhere forget to "reset" retrieved model collection - I am very new to Backbone development so it is really possible.

I am sorry for not providing code samples but I want you to ask also something else - it is about how Backbone algorithm for "Remove nonexistent models if appropriate" works - can be found here https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L734

I was curious why my code crashes so I started to debugging backbone script itself (maybe not so good idea as it looks but I found out something interesting). In the provided link above you can see that backbone is iterating through models and deletes everything that is not needed. Its O.K. but I think that there is bug because backbone tries to iterate N times where N is `this.length` instead of `this.models.length`. In my case this two lengths are different. In my models I have for example 2 models but backbone tries to iterate 4 times because the value of `this.length` is 4.

Could please anybody explain to me why are these values different? I assume that `this.length` should be updated any time the length of `this.models` changes but in my case this is not happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a collection.fetch() somewhere try replacing it with collection.fetch({reset: true}) - it worked for me.